# StaleObjectStateException vs OptimisticLockException

Tags: hibernate, exception, concurrency, optimistic-concurrency

A StaleObjectStateException is being thrown in my app instead of OptimisticLockException (as I read I should expect this one) when optimistic concurrency problem occurs in my app. No need to post code, as it's the most basic concurrency problem - wrong version in a timestamp column.

How am I supposed to get OptimisticLockException, not the other one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

StaleObjectStateException is thrown when you use straight hibernate API. OptimisticLockException is thrown if you used JPA style hibernate. If this confuses you please read: [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

Use try catch block to catch the exception:

```
try {
  // your hibernate operation here
} catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
  // do something (eg: inform user update is conflicting)
}
```

It's worth noting OptimisticLockException occur due to other transaction has updated (hence created newer version of) the object before you got chance to do so. In a UI application it is common to prompt the user whether to overwrite / discard / merge his/her version of the object

Comment: I know how to catch exceptions :)
The problem is that a different exception is being thrown here. As I read in documentation and books, OptimisticLockException should be thrown in the case of optimistic concurrency. I'm getting StaleObjectStateException instead. I want the other one! :D

Comment: StaleObjectStateException is thrown when you use straight hibernate API. OptimisticLockException is if you used JPA style hibernate. If this confuses you please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: I've posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001990/hibernate-staleobjectstateexception-issue-calling-merge/50002168#50002168) which uses JPA and i'm still getting a StaleObjectStateException. Can you please clarify your answer?

Answer (score 1):

As of my analysis of Hibernate 3.5.2 (now bit old), I found they sometimes throw `OptimisticLockException` and sometimes `StaleObjectStateException`. Batch operations even throw `StaleStateException`, which is a superclass of `StaleObjectStateException`, but don't have the entity instance.

It seems to me as an unfinished refactoring, you probably need to catch both and react to both the same way.