# How does Java resolve JPA annotations behind the scenes

Tags: java, jpa, jvm

I am new to JPA. I am using relationship annotations, such as @OneToOne, @ManyToOne.

I would like to understand how does the java compiler read annotations and interpret them.

Comment: As far as I remember JPA is just declarations of API. Which implementation do you use?

Comment: you need to do some reading on the Oracle documentation site, it is way to expansive to address here. Annotations have been around a long time and how they work or do not work is very well documented and is a huge subject.

Answer (score 1):

Java Annotations and Java Reflection is what do the work of @OneToOne ; @ManyToOne behind the scenes --- and many other annotations used by JPA API Specification.

You can study and see how it works [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html). You can also write code that do the same "magic" like the JPA API. Also, you can read the Oracle [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) to understand how it works.

It is important to remember that Java Persistence API is a specification. The "behind scenes" of how it works resolving the Reflection / Annotations is equal to any other vendor implementation because the Java Virtual Machine resolves that in Runtime; wich means is a mechanism of the JVM.

To understand better what it means the JPA is a specification --- wich differs from a vendor implementation ---, please, read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate).