# difference between hibernate and jpa orm tool

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

1-This question  is to make the clear vision about the ORM  tool is provided in the the hibernate and Java persistence API.
2-I tried to explore this but I found not any satisfactory answer to make my vision clear about

Comment: What exactly is your questions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate 

try this.. already asked sir. So please avoid questions already been asked.. It may harm your reputation

Thank You

Comment: Okay Vikrant sir thank you very much.I am new user sir.Always feel free to recommend me.

Comment: My question is what is the difference between ORM of JPA and ORM of HIbernate @ MartinS