# why most of the peoples using hibernate with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

why most of the peoples preferred to use in hibernate with JPA,
what are the difference between usage of plain hibernate.
please give me clarification on this.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/why-i-choose-hibernate-for-my-project/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

Comment: i did not ask difference and usage of hibernate

Comment: Im not sure clarification is technical, Hibernate historically was the first (open source) implementation (before JPA standard), had community etc. The Holy War between Hibernate, Eclipselink show performance are comparable, extra features too. In last year I prefer Eclipselink, but old project I made with Hibernate. In years of java8 and new date/time API Datanucleus has his renaissance (javax.time isn't compatible with JPA 2.1, Datanucleus implement it)

Comment: ......read the answer posted by @grsdev7 , Hibernate is just the Implementor of JPA , if you use plain Hibernate you might benefit by its custom features but if in some time in future you want to change the JPA implementor f.e. include Spring Data or EclipseLink , it will be a pain in the ass to refactor your project , but if you are depending in JPA and simply passing Hibernate with a proper config ,  you could easily modify which implementor will be binded above

Comment: Good designed application should be build over pure JPA 2.1 API without extensions, but all extensions are used for different reasons