# Why to choose Spring Data JPA Over Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Why to choose Spring Data JPA Over Hibernate ? Assuming I am developing Spring MVC + Spring REST + Spring Security application using Oracle.

Comment: check this question, it may give you an insight into JPA and hibernate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: Hibernate is a JPA implementation whereas Spring Data JPA is a querying framework for JPA, so there is no choice between because they are two complete different things.

Comment: So are you saying that we can use both ? More details would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Spring Data` in your project, you are not going to write most of the low level data access operations like writing `SQL query`, `DAO classes` etc. `Spring Data` will generate everything dynamically at run-time by creating the `proxy instances` of your `abstract repositories` and perform the required operations. What you write is the `abstract interfaces` that define the required operations.