# When hibernate is capable of doing, Why JPA has been introduced?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When Hibernate is capable of doing everything, Why JPA has been introduced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

Comment: Internet search clearly is down again, hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is just specifications and Hibernate is an implementation, you can find further details here in this question [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate) .

If you use JPA with hibernate then you can swap out hibernate with any other alternate ORM. without modifying much code.

Its like `List` interface, now you use any implementation of list according to your need example `LinkedList`, `ArrayList` etc

Comment: Hi Ali, temporary comment to explain about [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15998602) that all occurrences of "thanks" on Stack Overflow should be removed, not added.

Comment: @Cœur, Yes actually I did not add it, it was there already but you are seeing it as added because someone has removed before my edit and I did not remove it.