# Migration from Hibernate 3.2 to 4.3.9 TransactionHelper class not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate but have been tasked to migrate from 3.2 to 4.3.9 I am having problems with class/methods not found. Typically getSession, TransactionHelper, SessionFactoryImplementor, PropertiesHelper.

If these are no longer available in version 4.2 what do I replace the above with?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags you are using Spring Framework. If you have this option, instead of using plain Hibernate switch to JPA (the difference is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)) with some friendly libraries e.g. [Spring Data JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/). This should abstract your code from the semantics of Hibernate version (although this is not that simple).

Please note that [Hibernate 5.3 was released on 24th Jul 2018](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/). By updating to 4.2 you are updating to a legacy version.

Comment: I cannot jump to 5.3 because the team suggested that we should first migrate from 3 to 4 for now then, later on, we can start looking at migrating to 5 since most of our projects are still using old tech.

Comment: Anyway I will look at the spring option and then see what I can do. Thank you.