# Why has javax.persistence-api been replaced by jakarta.persistence-api in spring data jpa starter?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've recently started to learn spring boot, data jpa. As I can see from [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/pom.xml), the spring boot data jpa starter uses `jakarta.persistence-api` instead of `javax.persistence-api`:

```xml
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   ...
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            ...
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

What is the differences between `jakarta.persistence-api` and `javax.persistence-api`? What is the reason of this replacement?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

From [Java Persistence API on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API):

> The **Java Persistence API (JPA), in 2019 renamed to Jakarta Persistence**, is a Java application programming interface specification that describes the management of relational data in applications using Java Platform, Standard Edition and Java Platform, Enterprise Edition/Jakarta EE.

After Java EE was open sourced by Oracle and gave the rights to the Eclipse Foundation they were legally required to change the name from Java as Oracle has the rights over the Java brand. The name Jakarta was chosen by the community. You can find more information by reading [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) and [Jakarta EE - No Turning Back](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/may/noturningback.php).

Comment: Thanks - but which API shall be used and when? I started a new spring-boot project after a long time, and now I am confused about the correct package to use and why?

Comment: @AbdealiChandanwala you can refer to this answer as it's a bit more complicated than that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarta-and-javax

Comment: Spring Boot 3/Spring Framework 6 have upgraded to Jakarta EE 9+, hence the corresponding version of Spring Data JPA is now on the "jakarta" versions of things. Spring Boot 2.7 and earlier are still on "javax" versions of things.