# Using Spring Data 2.6.1 with Eclipselink and Jakarta 3, is it possible?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, spring-data, eclipselink

We are currently bumping dependency versions of a Spring project with persistence based on [JPA with Eclipselink](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-eclipselink). During the upgrade process I learned about [Eclipselink switching to Jakarta namespace](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/3.0.php) starting with version 3.0 due to legal reasons as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021815/why-has-javax-persistence-api-been-replaced-by-jakarta-persistence-api-in-spring).

We succeeded in updating the code so that we use Jakarta Persistence API 3.0.0 **independently** from Spring Data. The migration is quite straight forward:

- Bump Eclipselink version to 3.0.x
- Add an explicit dependency to Jakarta 3
- Replace `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence` in the code and in `persistence.xml`

Now I am looking into configuring Spring Data to use Eclipselink with Jakarta 3.0.0, but I noticed Spring still depends on JAXB 2.2.3. When I override the version in my Maven project, Spring Data complains on startup:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.<clinit>(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at com.mycompany.sandbox.springjpaeclipselinkfix.SpringApp.main(SpringApp.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Apparently, it tries to create a persistence unit called `default` and fails to load `javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory` (obviously, it is now in the `jakarta.persistence` package).

My understanding is that Spring Data's code depends on Jakarta 2 and using Jakarta 3 is not supported. However, it should be possible to use Eclipselink as Spring Data persistence provider and Eclipselink does support Jakarta 3. I am puzzled at this point and I cannot find any current examples for this, only old stuff relating to `javax.persistence`.

1. **Is it possible to configure Spring Data to use Eclipselink 3 and Jakarta 3, or should I stick to the old namespace for now?**
2. **And if it's possible, can you point me to some current examples?**

Obviously, one could fork Spring Data JPA's code and do the migration but I have not enough resources to maintain a branch.

I am posting also the relevant parts of my pom.xml (the rest resembles a standard Spring Data project):

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <jakarta-persistence.version>3.0.0</jakarta-persistence.version>
        <eclipselink.version>3.1.0-M1</eclipselink.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta-persistence.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Other tags: Jakarta EE 9, Jakarta Persistence 3.0, Java 17.

Comment: I found another link that might help: [A Guide to JPA with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa). I am looking into "The JPA Spring Configuration With Java in a Non-Boot Project" and creating a custom PersistenceJPAConfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6). Apparently the roadmap includes switching to the jakarta namespace "in Q4 2022":

> As announced at SpringOne yesterday, Spring Framework 6 and Spring
> Boot 3 are planned towards a high-end baseline for their general
> availability in Q4 2022:
>
> ```
> Java 17+ (from Java 8-17 in the Spring Framework 5.3.x line)
> Jakarta EE 9+ (from Java EE 7-8 in the Spring Framework 5.3.x line)
> ```
>
> This forward-looking baseline will provide significant benefits in our
> API design and integration efforts, shining through to your
> application code and future-proofing the framework as well as your
> applications for many years to come. However, it comes at a cost, of
> course: Spring Framework 6 and Spring Boot 3 based applications will
> require a minimum of JDK 17 at runtime, as well as a minimum of Tomcat
> 10 / Jetty 11 (for Jakarta EE 9 compatibility). Even more importantly,
> there might be some changes required in your application source code:
> e.g. the javax to jakarta namespace change in Jakarta EE 9 wherever
> you’re touching the Servlet API, JPA, Bean Validation, etc.

It is thus a matter of waiting until the change is rolled out by Spring.