# Spring Boot application not starting in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot 2.6 application that I've been running with embedded Tomcat, but for certain reasons I need to change the application to run inside tomcat.

The server I'm deploying the application to is Centos 7 and Tomcat 10.

The issue I'm having is that when I start tomcat, it says it's deploying the web application, but I don't see the spring startup in the catalina.log file and the application is never accessible in the browser. It seems that while the application is being deployed, Spring isn't being started.

The main class is setup like this;

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and here's the Maven configuration;

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mydemoapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>intranet</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2020.02.07.1</version>
    <name>mydemoapp</name>
    <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.ghost4j.repository.releases</id>
            <name>Ghost4J releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.ghost4j.org/maven2/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.ghost4j.repository.snapshots</id>
            <name>Ghost4J snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.ghost4j.org/maven2/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Open CSV -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- barcodes depends on kernel -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- forms depends on kernel and layout -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- kernel depends on io -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- layout depends on kernel -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- pdfa depends on kernel -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.17</version>
            <!-- sign depends on kernel, layout and forms -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.woo</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmltopdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>intranet</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot 3 - Jakarata. and Javax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarata-and-javax). Or, phrased differently: Use Tomcat 9. Apart from Spring Boot 2.x, you also have a dependency on javax.servlet, which Tomcat 10 doesn't provide.

Comment: Thank you. I will try downgrading to Tomcat 9 and see how I get on

Comment: Sadly, downgrading to Tomcat 9 results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for me is moving the application from apache-tomcat/web to a subfolder apache-tomcat/web/<app's name>