# Custom Spring Boot 3 Starter does not create ConfigurationProperties beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, configurationproperties

I am creating a Maven artifact with following classes and configuration in custom Spring Starter project:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "commons.time.formats")
@Getter
@Setter
public class TimeFormatConf {
... fields
}
```

```java
@Component
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TimeFormatConf.class)
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DateTimeConfigurer {
  private final TimeFormatConf timeFormatConf;

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void configureTimeFormat() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeFormatConf.getDynamicZone()));
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", timeFormatConf.getDynamicZone());
  }
}
```

And spring.factories (`src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`):

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
[package].DateTimeConfigurer,\
...
```

When I try to autowire a TimeFormatConf class my spring application crashes at start up as it cannot find a bean of TimeFormatConf class:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.some.package.b.Class required a bean
> of type 'com.some.package.a.TimeFormatConf' that could not be found.

The artifact is present with correct configuration on classpath. So it has to do something with either declaration or configuration of Spring.

I have also tried adding `@Component` on properties class and `@ComponentScan` on configuration class does not have any effect.

Reverting to Spring Boot 2.7.7 on both projects fixed the problem. So it seems to be a bug or at least lack of documentation. I have opened an issue to follow this up with spring team: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33720

Comment: PS Using spring boot 3.0.1

Comment: try adding the NoArgsConstructor on the class TimeFormatConf but with the code you have now it should be working maybe its something with the new version of spring also use RequiredArgsConstructor annotation if you are using final also you can comment Configuration and EnableConfigurationProperties(TimeFormatConf.class) in DateTimeConfigurer i dont think they are doing anything

Comment: Well, I have tried adding those, but it does not make a difference. Also, properties are bound through setters unless you specify constructor binding annotation.

Comment: ok i just tested and you just need to add Configuration annotation to TimeFormatConf class and it will work no problem

Comment: update: just put ConfigurationPropertiesScan annotation on the  main class near the SpringBootApplication adding Configuration annotation was the old way of doing it my bad

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There seems to be a change in the way configurations beans are detected by Spring since version 2.7, it seems to be covered in this migration [guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files)

Basically, instead of providing configuration in `META-INF/spring.factories`, you would do so in `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`

Comment: With spring boot 3.x.x this a breaking change. backward compatibility with `META-INF/spring.factories` is not supported.