# BeanCreationException error creating Repository with Spring Boot - "Not a managed type" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, repository, entity

I am trying to learn Spring and most particularly Spring Boot, and I have made a set of classes, starting with a main, a model class and a repository class. However, when I try to start the main app, Spring does not boot and throws the following error :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.2)

2023-02-03T15:45:58.473+01:00  INFO 28388 --- [           main] com.openclassrooms.api.ApiApplication    : Starting ApiApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 28388 (C:\Users\Bastien ROY\OneDrive\Projet Transversal\api\target\classes started by Bastien ROY in C:\Users\Bastien ROY\OneDrive\Projet Transversal\api)
2023-02-03T15:45:58.477+01:00  INFO 28388 --- [           main] com.openclassrooms.api.ApiApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-03T15:45:59.506+01:00  INFO 28388 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
2023-02-03T15:45:59.813+01:00  INFO 28388 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:bca07d4f-a527-494b-9b3f-460ee65f30e9'
2023-02-03T15:46:01.019+01:00 ERROR 28388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.openclassrooms.api.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.openclassrooms.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

This bug keeps on appearing, whatever correction I try to make to repair it.

My Entity class :

```
package com.openclassrooms.api.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String mail;

    private String password;

}
```

My repository class :

```
package com.openclassrooms.api.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

My main class :

```
package com.openclassrooms.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.openclassrooms.api.models")
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello World !");
    }

}
```

My dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.openclassrooms</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>API with SpringBoot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My project properties in application.properties :

```
#Global configuration
spring.application.name=api

#Tomcat configuration
server.port=9000

#Log level configuration
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.com.openclassrooms=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat=INFO

#H2 Configuration
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

If you have any idea of where the problem could come from, I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: The @Repository Annotation is not necessary on your EmployeeRepository. This will be managed automatically because you extend the CrudRepository.

Comment: Good to know, thank you ! However it does not solve the problem :(

Comment: Have you tried to remove the @EntityScan? I would also try to remove the two hibernate dependency in your pom.

Comment: I would also add following properties to you applicatipn.properties to tell spring boot your datasource: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using spring jpa dependency you dont need hibernate alone

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Your imports in Employee come from

```
javax.persistence

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

change it for

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
```

please see
[javax vs jakarta in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarta-and-javax)

also `@EntityScan("com.openclassrooms.api.models")` is unnecessary

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this solved everything ! I was following a tutorial on Spring 2.idkwhatversion, which did use javax, and i didn't know it changed since !