# How can I resolve the issues I'm facing with annotations in my backend?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, gradle, backend

I am Developing a back-end with Spring Boot: and I have to define my data models as Java entities and use annotations to map them to the corresponding database tables

But I keep getting an error when I try to add the annotations

[image: here is my file class and the errore]

```
   package com.java.filemanager.SpringReactFileManager.Entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class File {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "file_name", nullable = false)
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "file_path", nullable = false)
    private String filePath;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;
    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}''''''
```

I added the dependencies for Gradle and even ran it in the build was successful
[image]

Here is my application. properties.Im not sure if it is connected to the MySQL database and I'm not sure how to run and check to see if it is
[image]

Comment: Please paste the code instead of images. As solution for your problem you might try to: replace imported javax with jakarta. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarta-and-javax

Answer (score 0):

The current problem seems to be a compile-time problem.
You can first modify the problem corresponding to the code according to the error message in the lower left corner.

For example, adjust the file name `SharedFileID.java` to `SharedFileId.java` to match the class name.

Answer (score 0):

replace imported javax with jakarta