javax-maven-plugin error due parsing wsdl from url or file
I have problem with parsing wsdl info form url
here my dependencies for soap
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

here plugin which i use
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>${****}</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                    <packageName>${*****}</packageName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

When i doing build, cathc error
[WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'PayOrderISOWebService?xsd=1', because 'https' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
line 4 of https://******
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 5 of https://******
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 7 of https://******
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

Tryed do this request throw SoapUI, all ok, in request received normal xml

Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarta-and-javax
