Cannot resolve symbol 'NotEmpty' using SpringBoot 3.x
I'm starting to study JavaSpring and I want to validate the attributes of my class.
I'm using this annotation: @NotEmpty to validate the fields.
However, I am receiving the following message: Cannot resolve symbol 'NotEmpty
I think it's a problem with the import since the following is happening when trying to import:
Cannot resolve symbol 'validation'
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

I don't know what's wrong.
How can I resolve this so the annotation works.
The class follows:
package models;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import java.util.Objects;

@Document(collection = "customers")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Customer {

 @Id
 private String id;

 @NotEmpty(message = "CPF is required")
 private String cpf;

 @NotEmpty(message = "Name is required")
 private String name;

 @NotEmpty(message = "Email is required")
 private String email;

 @NotEmpty(message = "Phone is required")
 private String phone;

 private Address address;

 // Constructors
 public Customer() {
 }

 public Cliente(String cpf, String name, String email, String phone, Address address) {
 this.cpf = cpf;
 this.name = name;
 this.email = email;
 this.phone = phone;
 this.address = address;
 }

 // Equals and HashCode
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
 if (this == o) return true;
 if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
 Customer customer = (Customer) o;
 return Objects.equals(id, client.id) && Objects.equals(cpf, client.cpf);
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
 return Objects.hash(id, cpf);
 }
}

Here's the build.gradle:
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.mf-clientes'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
  toolchain {
  languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
  }
}

configurations {
  compileOnly {
  extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
  implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
  implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}


tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}


For Annotations NotNull yes, but for NotEmpty it didn't work.

That's strange; from your error message, I would think that the problem is importing javax.validation in general, not any particular class within it.

modern versions of Java libraries use jakarta instead of javax - try jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
See relevant Jakarata Validation documentation

Yup.  The OP is mixing javax and jakarta in the same app.  Bad idea.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179660/spring-boot-3-jakarta-and-javax.
