Maven build error while upgrading parent version at pom file
I am trying to upgrade maven parent version facing this error while building
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:396) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:405) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:401) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:627) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:664) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:35) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:26) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:366) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:575) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:107) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 20 more

it should run without generating any runtime issue,

Spring moved from Javax to Jakarta, one of your dependency is looking for javax which doesn't exist anymore https://stackoverflow.com/q/71179660/175554
