# JPA eclipselink 3.0 implementation not working with java 11 and giving java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, java-11, apache-ranger

I am using java and eclipselink implemetation of JPA in my project,
I need to upgrade my app from java 8 to java 11, so based on recommendation of official website eclipselink, upgraded eclipselink to 3.0 https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/releases/3.0.php for java 11
but after upgrading the elcipselink version I started seeing below error,

```
[ERROR ][main] 
Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'defaultEntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEntityManagerFactory' 
defined in ServletContext resource [/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)|   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)|      at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)|        at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)|      at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)|  at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)|       at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)| at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)|        at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)| at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)| at 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)|      at 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)|     at 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)|    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)|   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)|   at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)|     at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)|     at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)|  at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)| at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)|     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)|        at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)|  at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)|     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)|     at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)|  at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)| at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)|     at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)|      at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)|    at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)|      at
 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)|        at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)|   at
```

This is working properly with java8 * eclipselink 2.5.2 combination, but I need to upgrade my java to 11 hence need to upgrade eclipselink to 3(old eclipselink version is not supported on java 11) but facing this issue. please help. thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Your Spring setup doesn't support Jakarta persistence - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024749/496099 as you'll need to update Spring and likely modify some configuration and classes to use Jakarta.persistence packages in place of javax.persistence

Comment: I have tried updating spring too but there I see compilation failure in my code.

Comment: Because is isn't a straight jar replacement - packages have changed. Take a look at the Spring docs for the version you are migrating to and they should tell you what might need to be changed.