# Enterprise development with Java

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am doing this course called enterprise development with java. Our lecture gave us the below code, but i am getting error messages saying the import javax.persistence connot be resolved. Ive been searching for answers but now. Please help.

```
package Guest; 
 
import java.io.Serializable; 
import java.sql.Date; 
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; 
import javax.persistence.Id; 
 
 
@Entity 
public class guest implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
 
    // Persistent Fields: 
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    Long id; 
    private String name; 
    private Date signingDate; 
 
    // Constructors: 
    public guest() { 
    } 
 
    public guest(String name) { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.signingDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    } 
 
    // String Representation: 
    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return name + " (signed on " + signingDate + ")"; 
    } 
}`
```

I tried recreating the project, follwed some inline suggestion, enabling JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996933/1842599
I quote:

> The javax.persistence package was moved to a newly named dependency (jakarta.persistence. The persistence package is part of the larger JPA (Java Persistence API). See [Intro to JPA](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3379043/what-is-jpa-introduction-to-the-java-persistence-api.html)

Can that be the problem in your case, that you're just using the wrong version of JPA?