# Trying to use Spring JPA @Entity - "Entity cannot be resolved to a type" error

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

I am working a Spring Boot project, using Maven. I am trying to use JPA for database connection and operations.

When I use @Entity and other annotations on the entity classes, I get an "Entity cannot be resolved to a type" error (same with all other JPA annotations).

My pom.xml includes the following dependencies.

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector/J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

One of the entity classes is defined as follows.

```
    package com.somedomain.firstSpringApp.entities;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "birth_date")
        private Date birthDate;

        @Column(name = “phone_number”)
        private String phone;

        // Getters and setters

    }
```

In the import statements above, javax.persistence "cannot be resolved".

My Spring version is as follows.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Would really appreciate any help on figuring out what I am missing.

Thanks.

I have already tried restarting the IDE (Eclipse) to resync. That did not fix the issue.

Eclipse's suggestions for fix include - Import 'Entity' (jakarta.persistence). Is it possible that  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is too old for Spring 3.2.0?

Comment: Can you include in the snippet the imports from your `User` class?

Comment: maybe yout Entity class using javax . check your imports

Comment: Can you share the project structure? where the package "com...entities" is in relation to the package where the class with @ SpringBootApplication is present?

Comment: Yeah it is old code but a very new Spring Boot. If you remove all those import statements and let your IDE fix imports, it should put imports in place where javax is replaced with jakarta. I will vote to close this as a duplicate question with this specific answer in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996933/424903