I am writing a SpringBoot application but cant find the symbol @Entity
I´m having the issue @Entity not found.
I tryed to include the Maven dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

and the import clause:
import javax.persistence.Entity; 

I would like to know what are the dependencies and imports necessary to use the annotation @Entity.

It depends on the JPA version. What is the Spring Boot version you're using?

If that one is not working you should probably be using the jakarta one: import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

some reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa#initial

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996933/19801993 - here is the explanation.
